# use ajax call to load a view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to load a view through ajax passing in a post variable through controller following is my ajax call:

```
 $('#image_id').on('click',function(){
    var image_id = $('#image_id').val();
    alert(image_id);
    if(image_id != '')

    {
        alert('called');
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('Site/load_add')?>",
            method:"POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data:{add_id:image_id},
            success:function(data)
            {
                window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('Site/load_add')?>";
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

I am using the add_id to retrieve data from the database in my controller below:

```
public function load_add()
{
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    $data['advert_data']=$this->Product_model->get_specific_add($this->input->post('add_id'));

    $array_info2 = array(
        "title" => "View Add"
    );
    $this->load->view('include/header', $array_info2);
    $this->load->view('include/navbar_logged_in');
    $this->load->view('Site/site_load_add',$data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer');

}
```

I am getting an error at the point of data retrieval from DB, as the model does not have the add_id. Following is my model code

```
 public function get_specific_add($image_id)

{
    $this->db->select('adverts.title,adverts.item_condition,adverts.add_type,adverts.address,adverts.price,adverts.negotiable,adverts.product_description,adverts.create_time, users.first_name,users.last_name,users.mobile,users.email,users.image_name');
    $this->db->from('adverts,countries,states,cities,users');
    $this->db->where('adverts.id= $image_id_new');
    $this->db->where('adverts.country_id=countries.id');
    $this->db->where('adverts.city_id=states.id');
    $this->db->where('adverts.area=cities.id');
    $this->db->where('adverts.user_id=users.id ');
    $this->db->where('adverts.id= $image_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();


}
```

Appreciate if someone can help me on this. The page i am trying to load is Site/site_load_add. Thanks

Comment: what you get in `$data['advert_data']` ? is correct data which you are expecting?

Comment: are you getting $this->input->post('add_id');  in  `load_add()`?

Comment: Product_model->get_specific_add, does not get the post variable add_id, so the page returns database error.  $this->db->where('adverts.id= $image_id');, the $image_id does not contan add_id in my ajax request.

Comment: are you getting $this->input->post('add_id'); in load_add()?  No returns nothing...

Comment: so problem is here , first get $this->input->post('add_id'); this.

Answer (score 0):

You've call same url with both `GET|POST`, First call `POST` is ok, but in `GET` that's your error.

```js
$.ajax({
    // first call is OK!
    url:"<?php echo site_url('Site/load_add')?>",
    method:"POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data:{add_id:image_id},
    success:function(data)
    {
        // BUG HERE, This's a GET call and with No query string
        // Will `$this->input->post('add_id')` found nothing.
        window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('Site/load_add')?>";
    }
```

Comment: this is your answer?

Comment: the OP does not sends the `image_id` in `function load_add()` by ajax call.

Comment: in ajax call is ok, but in ajax success have `window.location.href` that call to `load_add` again.

Comment: so what OP does?

Comment: thinks `window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('Site/load_add')?>"` is a mistake, may be `<?php echo site_url('Redirect to some url')?>` Or not `<?php echo site_url('Site/load_add?add_id=123')?>` and then in `load_add` check `input->get|post(add_id)`

Comment: didnt work, what i simply want to get done is to get the add_id related information from database and show in the new page. What i have done here is submit the post data via ajax call to the controller, then to model to extract data from db and show in a view. I put a different page to load, still the post data is not in this new page either.

Comment: if you `success:function(data) { console.log(data) }`, the `data` should be `html` right? then you can show your `html data` via something like `popup` or `modal`, But if you just want to redirect to new page when click on image no need to ajax-call just `window.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('Site/load_add=')?>?add_id=' + image_id;` then in your controller change `$this->input->post('add_id')` to `$this->input->get('add_id')`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the support, I got this sorted by passing the ID of the advert a below:

```
public function load_add($id)
{

    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    $data['advert_data'] = $this->Product_model->get_specific_add($id);
    $data['adverts'] = $this->Product_model->get_adverts();//get database query output to the array

    $array_info2 = array(
        "title" => "View Add"
    );
    $this->load->view('include/header', $array_info2);
    $this->load->view('include/navbar_logged_in');
    $this->load->view('Site/site_load_add', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer');
}
```

Thanks